# Привести пример синонимов, не принадлежащих к одной части речи

Tags: синонимы, части-речи

В лингвистическом словаре есть такое утверждение:

> Синонимы, как правило, принадлежат к одной и той же части речи и выступают как взаимозаменяемые элементы высказывания.

Т.е. бывают и исключения. Помогите найти пример.

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, это относится к расширенному пониманию синонимов (более одного слова):

правильно (наречие)

без ошибок (предлог + существительное)

должным образом (прилагательное + существительное)

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется, но возможно есть и другие случаи; поэтому решил уточнить.

Answer (score 4):

Бывают синонимами и одиночные слова разных частей речи, ведь причастие, например, совмещает признаки глагола и прилагательного, поэтому часто бывает синонимом для прилагательного: грохочущий -  шумный,  шумливый,  рокочущий, многоголосый, бабахающий, громыхающий...

Ну, и фразеологизмы, разумеется, часто  относятся к разным частям речи:
быстро: во все лопатки, сломя голову, в мгновенье ока, высунув язык, со всех ног.

Comment: Грохочущий, шумный. Может быть, здесь причастие сначала переходит в прилагательное, а потом становится синонимом для другого прилагательного.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос о синонимах, как мне кажется, должен иметь более четкое решение, чем просто рассуждение на тему (это же лексикология, вроде бы точная наука), хорошо бы к академическим справочникам обратиться.

Меня смущает, например, следующее:

1) Существует три формулировки на эту тему: а) синонимы ВСЕГДА относятся к одной части речи . б) синонимы, КАК ПРАВИЛО,   относятся к одной части речи . в) У Розенталя дается подробная классификация синонимов, но про отношение к одной части речи НИЧЕГО НЕ СКАЗАНО.

У Розенталя есть понятие о степени сложности синонимов, когда одно слово имеет в качестве синонима фразеологизм (но следует учитывать, фразеологизм имеет значение одного слова).

ПРИМЕР

Он пишет правильно,  без ошибок, должным образом. Наверное, это  однородные обстоятельства, а не синонимы. Синонимы должны образовывать синонимические ряды, вряд ли разумно включать в ряд все однородные обстоятельства конкретного предложения.

Comment: Я уже столкнулся с тем, что в русском языке практически нигде нет чёткой классификации. Это касается морфем, частей речи, синонимов и всего остального. И это замечательно, ведь только по-настоящему живой язык нельзя запихать в структуру, придуманную человеком.

Comment: Философский подход, призывающий к созерцательности. Живой язык, как и живую природу,  нельзя описать одним правилом, одной наукой.  Поэтому в любой науке (и в грамматике тоже) следует четко определять  границы и задачи описания, которое всегда является МОДЕЛЬЮ но не самой природой во всем ее многообразии.  Но это единственный путь воздействия человека на природу или язык, иначе мы так бы и не вышли из каменного века, не научились говорить. С помощью ТОЧНОГО понятия о синонимах мы ИЗУЧАЕМ живой язык, а выводы будем применять в практической речи, делая ее точной, образной, выразительной.

Answer (score 1):

> Помогите найти пример.

К примеру:

***[НА](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/312836)*** (частица/междометие) = ***ВОЗЬМИ, ДЕРЖИ, БЕРИ…*** (глаголы)